# How to Process Data into a CSV File Along with Other Methods Like Copy and Clone?

Tags: java, csv

In my person class, I'm supposed to have a `toCSV()` method where I return a string for my fields.

- A `copy` method that accepts a `Person p` and copies all the data.
- A `copy` method that accepts all individual parameters.
- And then finally a `clone` method that returns a `Person` with a copy of the data.

I wrote the methods off of what I think it is asking for but I'm still confused overall on what it is looking for.

I feel like my code for each of these methods is very redundant and not what the problem is looking for.

I haven't tackled the clone method cause I think the previous three methods are incorrect.

```
    public class Person {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String address;
        private String city;
        private String state;
        private String zipCode;

        public Person (String firstName, String lastName, String address, String city, String state, String zipCode) {

        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }

        public String getCity() {
            return this.city;
        }

        public void setCity(String city) {
            this.city = city;
        }

        public String getState() {
            return state;
        }

        public void setState(String state) {
            this.state = state;
        }

        public String getZipCode() {
            return zipCode;
        }

        public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
            this.zipCode = zipCode;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "FirstName: " + firstName + "\nLastName: " + lastName + "\nAddress: " + address + "\nCity: " + city + "\nState: " + state + "\nZipCode: " + zipCode;
        }

        public void toCSV() throws FileNotFoundException {
            PrintWriter file = new PrintWriter(new File("Customer.csv"));
            file.append(this.firstName);
            file.append(",");
            file.append(this.lastName);
            file.append(",");
            file.append(this.address);
            file.append(",");
            file.append(this.city);
            file.append(",");
            file.append(this.state);
            file.append(",");
            file.append(this.zipCode);
        }

        public void copy(Person p) throws FileNotFoundException {       
            PrintWriter file = new PrintWriter(new File("Customer.csv"));
            file.append(p.firstName);
            file.append(p.lastName);
            file.append(p.address);
            file.append(p.city);
            file.append(p.state);
            file.append(p.zipCode);
        }

        public void copy(String firstName, String lastName, String address, String city, String state, String zipCode) throws FileNotFoundException {
            PrintWriter file = new PrintWriter(new File("Customer.csv"));
            file.append(firstName);
            file.append(lastName);
            file.append(address);
            file.append(city);
            file.append(state);
            file.append(zipCode);
        }
```

To be completely honest I am unsure the exact results.

What I'm understanding is that it should return a file with the input line being `firstName,lastName,address,city,state,zipcode`, I have yet to run it because there are a lot of other pieces I'm missing.

However, I think my problem is that each of the methods will be creating its own new file and I believe it should all be under the same one `Customer.csv`.

I know this is pretty vague but I just need some help to see if my code is on the right track or that it completely is redundant and isn't going to work how it's intended to.

Comment: *I'm supposed to have a toCSV() method where I return a string for my fields* - Ask yourself whether you think that your code does this.

Comment: bro.. what does this even mean. If I knew that then I wouldn't have asked yall for help

Answer (score -1):

```
    public void toCSV( File customerFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
        doFileOp(customerFile, new Person (this.firstName, this.lastName, this.address, this.city, this.state, this.zipCode));
    }

    public void copy(Person p, File customerFile) throws FileNotFoundException {       
        doFileOp(customerFile, p);
    }

    public void copy(String firstName, String lastName, String address, String city, String state, String zipCode, File customrFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
        doFileOp(customerFile, new Person (firstName, lastName, address, city, state, zipCode));
    }

    private void doFileOp(File customerFile, Person p) {
         PrintWriter file = new PrintWriter(customerFile);
         customerFile.append(p.firstName);  file.append(",");
         customerFile.append(p.lastName);  file.append(",");
         customerFile.append(p.address);  file.append(",");
         customerFile.append(p.city);  file.append(",");
         customerFile.append(p.state);  file.append(",");
         customerFile.append(p.zipCode);  file.append(",");
    }
```